# Passing array of objects in java and saving the array of objects in the called method

Tags: java

I wrote some code to return me an array of objects.  How do I save those objects in the called method?

```
   public Ticket[] getOpenTicket() {
        int ticketcount = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < ticket.length; i++) {
            if (ticket[i] != null && ticket[i].getResolvedBy() == null) {
                ticketcount = ticketcount + 1;
                // System.out.println("Ticket raised by : " +
                // ticket[i].getTicketno());
            }
        }

        Ticket[] opentickets = new Ticket[ticketcount];
        for (int i = 0; i < ticket.length; i++) {
            if (ticket[i].getResolvedBy() == null) {
                opentickets[i] = ticket[i];
            }
        }
        return opentickets;

    }
```

This is the called function from where I am calling openticket:

```
TicketDaoMemImpl tdmi=new TicketDaoMemImpl();
Ticket [] obj1=tdmi.getOpenTicket();
```

Thanks

Comment: Where is tickettype defined? Are you sure it has been initialized? Please post enough code that we can reproduce the issue.

Comment: yes i m sure it is initialised

Comment: See my answer now that you have updated your code.

Comment: Not sure if you've edited your question/post and removed something, but in the current code posted, you reference `ticket` which is presumably an array but it is never declared (unless you have it declared as a global array somewhere in your class?) As posted, this wouldn't compile.

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't that look more like this:

```
public class CheckTicket {
    public Ticket [] openTicket() {
        return arrayOfTickets; // wherever that comes from
    }
}

CheckTicket cc = new CheckTicket();
Ticket[] t1 = cc.openTicket();
```

Comment: Tried the above code but it is still throwing a null pointer exceptions

Answer (score 0):

In this line of code

```
Ticket[] opentickets = new Ticket[ticketcount];
  for (int i = 0; i < ticket.length; i++) {
    if (ticket[i].getResolvedBy() == null) {
```

can't ticket[i] be null? It seems like that is most likely causing your issue - you call a method on what may be a null reference.

You should change you loop to something like:

```
Ticket[] opentickets = new Ticket[ticketcount];
int ticketIndex = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < ticket.length; i++) {
  if (ticket[i] != null && ticket[i].getResolvedBy() == null) {
    opentickets[ticketIndex] = ticket[i];
    ticketIndex++;
  }
}
```